# Django - How do I use the URL template tag in a format_html safe string?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I'm trying to include the URL template tag in a string that I have created using the format_html method:

```
message = format_html(
            '''<div>
               <p>{0} wants to join {1}!</p>
               {% url 'accounts:detail' pk={2} as profile_url %}
               <p>
               View their
               <a href="{{ profile_url }}">profile</a>
               </p>
               <div>Approve</div>
               <div>Deny</div>
               </div>
           ''',
           self.request_user.username,
           self.lab.name,
           self.request_user.pk)
```

The html that is outputted to the browser looks like this:

```
<a href="{ url 'accounts:detail' pk=4}">profile</a>
```

Basically my url tag without the %'s.

I have tried escaping the % by typing:

```
{%% url 'accounts:detail' pk={2} as profile_url %%}
```

But I receive the same output.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you choosing to do this with format_html? Why not just put it in an actual template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly create the URL with `reverse()`:

```
message = format_html(
        '''<div>
           <p>{0} wants to join {1}!</p>
           <p>
           View their
           <a href="{2}">profile</a>
           </p>
           <div>Approve</div>
           <div>Deny</div>
           </div>
       ''',
       self.request_user.username,
       self.lab.name,
       reverse('accounts:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.request_user.pk})
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try using
`{{ profile_url|safe }}` or use `{% autoescape %}` [Autoescappe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape)